# Autolayout error - Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints

Tags: macos, cocoa, autolayout, swift2

This question is related to the question I asked previously of how to add a view defined in a separate xib [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34736540/how-to-add-a-userview-in-ib). I'm still struggling with this and now I'm getting this layout specific error so I think it is better to ask a new question.

I have 2 xib's and I'm trying to insert the view from xib1 into a NSView place-holder on xib2, and I want the view from xib1 to be resized when the view is resized.

This is the code where I attempt to set left / right constraints.

```
    let placeholder: NSView = self.m_viewPlaceHolder;
    let insert: NSView = UserView01().view;
    insert.frame = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: placeholder.frame.width, height: placeholder.frame.height);
    placeholder.addSubview(insert);

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "NSConstraintBasedLayoutVisualizeMutuallyExclusiveConstraints");
    let hor = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[view]-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["view" : insert]);
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(hor);
```

and this is the error I see in the trace

```
2016-01-12 20:49:09.307 SubView01[9240:308241] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints:
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000087800 H:|-(NSSpace(20))-[NSView:0x608000120500]   (Names: '|':NSView:0x6080001206e0 )>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x6000000842e0 h=--& v=&-- H:|-(0)-[NSView:0x608000120500]   (Names: '|':NSView:0x6080001206e0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000087800 H:|-(NSSpace(20))-[NSView:0x608000120500]   (Names: '|':NSView:0x6080001206e0 )>

Set the NSUserDefault NSConstraintBasedLayoutVisualizeMutuallyExclusiveConstraints to YES to have -[NSWindow visualizeConstraints:] automatically called when this happens.  And/or, break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
2016-01-12 21:00:19.409 SubView01[9240:308241] Clicked on overlapping visualized constraints: (
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000087800 H:|-(NSSpace(20))-[NSView:0x608000120500]   (Names: '|':NSView:0x6080001206e0 )> (Actual Distance - pixels):0",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x6000000842e0 h=--& v=&-- H:|-(0)-[NSView:0x608000120500]   (Names: '|':NSView:0x6080001206e0 )> (Actual Distance - pixels):0"
)
```

The only constraints I have added in the designer is left/top/right/bottom 0 pixel constraints on the placeholder to the main window, and on the label to the userview.

Answer (score 1):

There is a clash with the implicit autoresizing mask of the view.

Two options:

1. Set the mask to something suitable in Interface Builder by turning off AutoLayout, changing the mask and turn on AutoLayout again or uncheck `translates autoresizing mask into constraints` (if available).
2. Do the same thing programmatically either setting the mask

   ```
   view.autoresizingMask = [...]
   ```

   or disabling `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`

   ```
   view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   ```

Comment: unfortunately if I set insertview.translatemask=false then the insert view does not show.

Comment: Of course then you have to add sufficient constraints by yourself.

Comment: shouldn't the constraint added by  NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[... be sufficient ?. Sorry for these probably silly questions, but I have spend hours now and still have no idea how to use the autolayout for inserting a view

Comment: Easy answer: If you don't see anything, the constraints are not sufficient. Try to simulate your environment by creating a view in Interface Builder and set the constraints in the UI. Then translate it into visual format language.